# Is there a way to shortcut upper bounds in type parameters

Tags: scala

I am using the same upper bound type regularly throughout my code and am wondering if there is a way I can actually specify this as an actual type in order to clean up and abbreviate my code.

So say I have defined the following parameterized type for a class:

```
class MyClass[T] { ... }
```

and I end up referring to this throughout my code the following way:

```
class SomeClass[I <: MyClass[_]] { ... }
```

Is there a way I can do something like the following:

```
type M = [I <: MyClass[_]]   ???

class SomeClass[M] { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if create a short type alias for `MyClass[_]`? Like the following:

```
type M = MyClass[_]

class SomeClass[I <: M] { ... }
```

I know this does not exactly answer your question. But this is the best that came to my mind so far.